# Kill Process on failed restart

Tags: c#

I'm quite new to C# and i'm having trouble with a program i'm writing.

I'm trying to create a service that monitors another service, the service i'm monitoring is notoriously unreliable and falls over constantly. Since it's written in a different language and the person who wrote it is long gone, our only options is to use a separate program to make sure its up and responding.

I've written a service that sends a message to the service, and if it gets a response, doesn't do anything, if it doesn't get a response, it initiates the restart. This essentially attempts to STOP the service, then start it again when it's done, or in case of it not responding to this, kills the process entirely.

it *seems* to work most of the time, but I've been having trouble with process kill. In the log i'm getting the error

`System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: An instance of the service is already running`

Which tells me that the process kill is not kicking in when the service is not responding to the stop.

Can someone please tell me what i'm doing wrong here?

```
 public static void Restart(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds,bool debug)
    {
        ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
        try
        {
            int millisec1 = Environment.TickCount;
            TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);

            if ((service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Running)) || (service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending)))
            {
                service.Stop();
                service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);
            }
            // count the rest of the timeout
            int millisec2 = Environment.TickCount;
            timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds - (millisec2 - millisec1));
            // if STILL running, hard kill the process
            if ((service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Running)) || (service.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending)))
            {
                Library.WriteErrorLog("Service not responding to STOP command, killing process: " + serviceName);
                foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName(serviceName))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        process.Kill();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Library.WriteErrorLog("Process Kill failed: " + ex.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            service.Start();
            service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);
        }
        catch (System.ServiceProcess.TimeoutException ex)
        {
            if (debug)
            {
                Library.WriteErrorLog("Restart Timed out: " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Library.WriteErrorLog("Failed to restart Services: " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: To be robust, perhaps you need a
`service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, ...);` before `service.Start()`

Comment: What's the rationale of checking the service status before killing the process if it exists and you've already made the decision to restart? If the process name exists and it can only be that service, wouldn't you want to kill it regardless? As you have it, you'd miss the StopPending state for example and the service would still be running. Perhaps not beautiful but if it's not an ideal situation anyway..

Comment: HI Steve, It's like that because I didn't know of a better way of doing it, I'm still quite new to the language. I'll take your suggestion on however as it does appear a better way of doing it.